# .htaccess-RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters. What's wrong?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
php_value short_open_tag 1
```

With this .htaccess I see i error log:

> [Thu Apr 21 17:37:33.868932 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6097] [client
>   11.33.11.33:30003] /var/www/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

What is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess - RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194168/htaccess-rewritecond-bad-flag-delimiters)

Comment: Is this your full htaccess?

Comment: "RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters" is often caused by erroneous _white space_. So can you please check with the trailing white spaces end of line.