# Codeigniter vhost LAMP configuration troubleshoot

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu

Running LAMP on UBUNTU 14LTS on virtualbox from win7 I found some hiccups.

I'm having trouble displaying my code igniter project in my machine. I have a followed some guides including this one: 
[tut 1](http://%20[1]:%20https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts) and [tut 2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)

I can make the current configuration show a single HTML page, called example.com but it cannot show a complete code igniter project, I get this error when running it through the localhost:

`NOT FOUND The requested URL /alpa_blog/en was not found on this server.`

The project I'm working on is very big so bitnami is a bitslow so I'm planning to change to LAMP that is why I wanted to try and see a little blog on my localhost.
I have not used the LAMP on apache 2.4+ so I'm a little confuse about how to edit some files on vhost and tie them to the config.php inside code igniter.

I've tried a lot of different combination things but no success yet. Now I have my files @:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/alpa_blog.com.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/alpa_blog.com.conf
```

Looking like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName alpa_blog.com
    ServerAlias www.alpa_blog.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alpa_blog.com/application

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And @ `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Plus my file `alpa_blog.com/config/config.php`  code igniter's folder looks like:

`$config['base_url'] = 'alpa_blog.com';`

My `etc/hosts` folder looks like:

`127.0.0.1       localhost
 127.0.1.1       alpalamp-VirtualBox
 127.0.1.1       example.com localhost
 127.0.1.1       alpa_blog.com localhost`

My `var/www/html` folder looks like:

`alpa_blog.com  ci  example.com  index.html  phpinfo.php`

Any pointers are much appreciated. Sorry for the your supposed to know that question, but it's driving me nuts.

EDIT:
I've tried several configurations on the `.htaccess` file.
This is my last version of the `.htaccess`:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
 RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And config.php is like:
 `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: Set `$config['base_url'] = 'alpa_blog.com';` to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://alpa_blog.com/';`.

Comment: @Tpojka No luck. The message did change to: `www.alpa_blog.com’s server DNS address could not be found.`

Comment: Edit question and post `.htaccess` file used.

Comment: @Tpojka Edited  `.htaccess` to what you see and the `$config['index_page'] = '';` of course is an empty string

Comment: You shouldn't leave empty string there. Check in [docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L14). Change `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alpa_blog.com/application` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alpa_blog.com` in case `alpa_blog.com` is directory where `index.php` resides. You have to set `sites-available` file only. Apache will set `sites-enabled` after restart of service. See in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) if you walked over all steps.

Comment: Is there a way o use only one vhost file like XAMP, WAMP or bitnami stacks use? I can't seem to be able to get around this configuration setup. It's getting boring.

Comment: Have you tried with changes I proposed?

Comment: I did, but no effect. I eve tried to move the root folder to `~/` but the same result dns cant be found. :/

Comment: But answer is yes. You can have multiple `<VirtualHost>` directives in one file.

Comment: It seems you are trying more than one thing at a time. Check one more time DO docs I linked. There is no other way to finish that right way.

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka, I just downloaded a new different repository and tried with no manipulation of vhosts at all on a different new VM and lamp is working. Yay! Hopefully I will hold. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while I found the answer, I thought to post it here just in case.

Going in the log file located at `var/log/apache2/error.log` I found this message:

`[core:alert] [...] /var/www/html/APP-NAME/www/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters`,  turns out that a regex expression was not properly written.

I Ended up by rewriting the rule on the `.htaccess`file like this:

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|uploads|robots\.txt) 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/  [L]`

Which solved the issue.

[This post also helped out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194168/htaccess-rewritecond-bad-flag-delimiters)